# images in grid layout on iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios

i want to display images in grid view like rows and columns.if i click the image should return a index value of image in the grid. i have no idea for this concept.if ur not understand my question i want like iPhone default photo gallery app viewing photos in a grid layout.!,i want to output like below screen shot and i am try to search but not found useful resource can any one help me with code or any tutorial links...!

[image]

Thanks...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try out [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) (its like a Grid-Tableview)

> AQGridView is an attempt to create something similar to NSCollectionView on the iPhone. 
>   ... ...
>
> AQGridView is based around the programming model of UITableView and
>   its associated classes. To create this class I looked long and hard at
>   how UITableView does what it does, and attempted to replicate it as
>   closely as possible. This means that if you are familiar with table
>   view programming on the iPhone or iPad, you will find AQGridView
>   simple to pick up.

Comment: Looks good but a little confused about the license. Is it free to use? Must the copyright notice appear in the Apple App store text? Would be a definite no-no if so.

Comment: its free, just place the copyright notice in the related header files where you include and use the AQGridView Classes. no need to publish the copyright in the app store text. as far as i know..!

Answer (score 1):

.. or you can try [Three20](http://three20.info/)

It provides both grid-view and fullscreen gallery.

Comment: please don't use Three20 in any project.

Comment: can you comment on that? I use it, I found it best solution from all available possibilities for sdk 3.2.5

Comment: okay offtopic: i used it in one project and kick it out, because i found to many side effects / memory leaks. e.g. if a paging UiScrollView contains UiScrollViews to zoom. edit: i used Three20 a year ago.

Comment: It's well known that Three20 has too many issues to be recommended. You're better off implementing whatever you need it to do on your own. Too buggy.